# Where should I create and present a Modal ViewController used throughout iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an iPhone application that uses a UITabBarController for its primary interface. The application also makes heavy use of modal UINavigationControllers presented from the various tabs.

There is a ViewController that I need to present modally which can be triggered from a wide variety of locations within the application. It seems like a terrible idea to duplicate the code which creates and presents it between all the viewControllers that trigger it. I would like to have this code in a single place and trigger it from whichever viewController wants to present it.

Where should this centralised location be? My root ViewController is a UITabBarController so no good there, and I hate lumping view functionality into the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new class file that has a function to present the view you want.  That way you only need to write the code once to present the modal view and each view that needs to use it can call the function on the helper class with one line of code.

```
@interface ApplicationHelper : NSObject {
}

+(void)showMyModalView:(UIViewController *)parentViewController;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ApplicationHelper.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ApplicationHelper

+(void)showMyModalView:(UIViewController *)parentViewController
{
      ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

      [parentViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Then in each view controller import the ApplicationHelper and call the showMyModalView method

```
[ApplicationHelper showMyModalView:me];
```

This allows you to keep all the view handling code in a separate file to your application delegate.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is better than repeating the same code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one UIViewController and implement some delegate method for it. Then you can present the view controller like this:

```
[currentViewController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

And when an event is fired in your view controller, it will delegate to the caller.

In this case, you write the code only one time for "YourViewController", then reuse it where ever you want. You can also use pushviewcontroller also:

```
[self.navigationController pushviewcontroller:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I understand how to present a modal ViewController. It makes no sense to me to pass a reference to a single ViewController through my application. Neither do I like using AppDelegate as a registry for global variables. It makes much more sense to me to use NSNotifications to trigger the modal ViewController's presentation from a single location. I just can't work out where that single location should be.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and pass the reference around.

Just `alloc] init];` a fresh instance where-ever you need to use it.

For example.

```
MyModalViewController *controller = [[MyModalViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: This seems really wasteful and ends up with unnecessarily duplicated code across the application.

Comment: Creating an object then displaying it, what's more simple than that?